# jQuery code not executing code when javascript is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container mt-4">
      <h1 class="text-left" style="margin-bottom: 50px">Daily Fridge & Freezer Monitoring Record</h1>
        <form action="/auth/21-TEMP-01b" method="post" id="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Fridge Or Freezer</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="fridgeFreezer" name="fridge">
              <option value="Fridge-1">Fridge 1</option>
              <option value="Fridge-2">Fridge 2</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges Fridge-1">
            <h4>Fridge 1</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature-1" name="temperature-1">

            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments-1" name="comments-1"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group fridges Fridge-2">
            <h4>Fridge 2</h4>
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature-2" name="temperature-2">

            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments-2" name="comments-2"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){


      $("select").change(function(){
      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("value")=="Fridge-1"){
          $(".fridges").not(".Fridge-1").hide();
          $(".Fridge-1").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="Fridge-2"){
          $(".fridges").not(".Fridge-2").hide();
          $(".Fridge-2").show();
      }
      else{
          $(".fridges").hide();
      }
      });
  })

  .change();

  var temp1 = document.getElementById('temperature-1');
  var form = document.getElementById('form');

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

    if(temp1.value === '' || temp1.value == null) {
      e.preventDefault()


      document.querySelector('#fridgeFreezer [value="Fridge-1"]').selected = true;

      alert("temp1 not fully filled")
    }
  })


  });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Idea**

I am trying to create form validation.

**Running the above code details**

You will see when you change the option in the drop down menu - different div element loads up. This is done through the jQuery code in the script.

**Option 1**

[image]

**Option 2**

[image]

**Next, Javascript**

I will be using Javascript to validate the form.

I only have started out validating the first div element of `fridge 1`. If value is empty I have an alert saying which input has not been filled.

In this scenario I have cleared out all data from Fridge 1 to run the `if` statement for the error.

Notice this line of code:

```
document.querySelector('#fridgeFreezer [value="Fridge-1"]').selected = true;
```

This re-selects the `option` to the one has the error.

But when I run it - this happens.

[image]

`Div` element of `fridge-2` is still showing? How come is the jQuery not executing ?

Comment: MDN says [`.selected` means "initially selected"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected). I think you have to change the value on the select element not the options once the page is rendered. Or maybe you could try triggering the 'change' event on the select manually if that's the bit you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Rup What do you mean by your first comment aha? I can't get my head around it to what you mean. You mean something like this: `document.getElementById('fridgeFreezer').value='Fridge-1';`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to trigger a change event if you want the change event listener to execute.

```
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    if(temp1.value === '' || temp1.value == null) {
      e.preventDefault()

      $('#fridgeFreezer').val("Fridge-1"); // can be simplified like this
      $('#fridgeFreezer').trigger("change"); // important line

      alert("temp1 not fully filled")
    }
  })
```